# Use cell number in cell reference in query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, cell, sql-like, google-query-language

I have this formula:

```
=query(A6:D848,"Select * where D LIKE'"&AC1&"' AND A <> 'Grand Total'",0)
```

Where AC1 has a value of 2 in it.

The above works a treat, but when I try to change the `LIKE` to a `>`, I get an error.

```
=query(A6:D848,"Select * where D >'"&AC1&"' AND A <> 'Grand Total'",0)
```

I'm assuming that it's because referencing a cell value gives back a string value an not an number, but I can't figure out how to get it to change to an number and make the query work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=query(A6:D848,"Select * where D > "&AC1&" AND A <> 'Grand Total'",0)
```

You received the error, because you had several quotes there.
`'"&AC1&"'` = `'` + `"` + `&AC1&` + `"` + `'`
You needed to remove the single quotes, because those were required for `LIKE` and not needed for `>`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it would have taking me ages to figure it out